# Prevent empty rsync email on cron

Tags: cron, rsync

I have a crontab job to sync a folder:

```
50 5 * * * /home/user/bin/sync-folder
```

This will execute an script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo rsync -rav --delete --log-file=/tmp/rsync-output /origin /destination
grep folder /tmp/rsync-output

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    cat /tmp/rsync-output
fi
```

The issue is that when there is nothing to sync, I get an email like this:

```
sending incremental file list

sent 343 bytes  received 17 bytes  720.00 bytes/sec
total size is 91,056  speedup is 252.93
```

What I wanted is to receive an email only where there are new changes. How can I prevent this kind of emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
50 5 * * * /home/user/bin/sync-folder
```

With this:

```
50 5 * * * /home/user/bin/sync-folder > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Add email inside script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo rsync -rav --delete --log-file=/tmp/rsync-output /origin /destination
grep folder /tmp/rsync-output

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    mailx -s "Rsync Complete at `date +"%F %T"`" myemail@account.com < /tmp/rsync-output
fi
```